# Criação Síncrona de Android SurfaceView

Tags: android, instanciar-objeto, callback

Criei uma subclassse de SurfaceView para abstrair operações de canvas, como drawBitmap (dentre outras), conforme mostrado abaixo:

```
public class MyView extends SurfaceView {

    public MyView(Context c) {
       super(c);
       this.canvasHolder = this.getHolder();
       this.canvasHolder.addCallback(surfaceHolderCallback);
    }

    public void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float width, float height, Paint p) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, width, height, p);
    }

    private SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceHolderCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
       @Override
       public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
           canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
       }

       @Override
       public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

       @Override
       public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}
    };

    public void flush() {
       this.canvasHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(this.canvas);
       this.canvas = this.canvasHolder.lockCanvas();
    }
```

A inicialização completa da SurfaceView depende do callback, na qual eu consigo acesso ao canvas que precisarei para manipular. De outra forma, eu recebo um NullpointerException na primeira chamada ao drawBitmap.

O problema é que eu quero permitir o uso da classe de forma bem direta, como mostrado abaixo. Para tal, eu preciso abstrair todo esse mecanismo de inicialização com callback e garantir que o drawBitmap tem acesso a um canvas válido (not null).

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso isso?

```
    MyView view = new MyView(getBaseContext());
    String source = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/abc.png";
    view.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(source).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true), 0, 0, null);
    view.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Se o "estado válido" de uma instância da classe *MyView* depende de uma chamada a um *callback* é como se a "criação da instância fosse assíncrona"

Não vejo como seja possível garantir que a instância não seja usada antes de ter o "estado válido".

No entanto é possível proporcionar ao utilizador um local onde possa usá-la com essa garantia.

Uma forma seria passar um *callback* no construtor e chamá-lo após o *canvas* ser válido.

Seria qualquer coisa assim:

```
public class MyView extends SurfaceView {

    //Iterface que o callback tem de implemantar
    public interface onCreatedCallback {
        void onCreated(MyView myView);
    }

    private final SurfaceHolder canvasHolder;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private onCreatedCallback onCreatedCallback;

    public MyView(Context c, onCreatedCallback callback) {
        super(c);
        //Guarda o callback
        onCreatedCallback = callback;
        this.canvasHolder = this.getHolder();
        this.canvasHolder.addCallback(surfaceHolderCallback);
    }

    public void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float width, float height, Paint p) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, width, height, p);
    }

    private SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceHolderCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

            //Nesta altura o canvas é valido
            if(onCreatedCallback != null){
                //Chama o callback
                onCreatedCallback.onCreated(MyView.this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}
    };

    public void flush() {
        this.canvasHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(this.canvas);
        this.canvas = this.canvasHolder.lockCanvas();
    }
}
```

A utilização seria assim:

```
final String source = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/abc.png";
new MyView(getBaseContext(), new MyView.onCreatedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCreated(MyView myView) {
        myView.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(source).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true), 0, 0, null);
        myView.flush();
    }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. De fato, estou ciente da possibilidade de adicionar o listener, mas não posso fazê-lo, pois tanto a criação do objeto quando a chamada às funções são feitas via reflexão, em código proveniente de outra linguagem, de forma síncrona. Um contexto bem específico.
Tentei concretizar alguns mecanismos de bloqueio com semáforo, ou sincronizando o holder, etc, mas não deu certo. =(